# Non-existent line numbers flickering

Tags: linum-mode

I have written till the 35th line in Emacs with activated line numbers (so my last line number is 35). When I am writing in the 32nd line there are line numbers flickering up to the 43rd line number (appearing only while writing) and when I stop they disappear.

The line numbers I mentioned (35 32 43) are just to explain the problem and they are simply my current line numbers. The same happens if I have 5 or 10 or any number of lines.

Why are those line numbers flickering and how can I make them stop appearing?

Comment: Can you reproduce the behaviour with a minimal Emacs session (aka `emacs -q`)?

Comment: @wasamasa How do I do that?

Comment: A few of the members of the Emacs development team recommend using nlinum-mode instead of linum-mode.  http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/nlinum.html

Comment: @Adam You open a terminal emulator, enter `emacs -q` and hit the enter key. Then you go ahead, enable `linum-mode` and write your text to see whether the problem still happens.

Comment: @wasamasa I did it and there is no problem.

Comment: @Adam Great, that means you're enabling some package that does interfere with linum, such as auto-complete-mode or something similiar. I suggest bisecting your init file by recursively commenting out half of it until you find the culprit.

Comment: @wasamasa Indeed the problem was auto-complete-mode! What can I do to avoid interference?

Comment: @Adam Unfortunately, neither `auto-complete-mode` nor its rival `company-mode` play well with line numbers. `auto-complete-mode` makes non-existent line numbers appear, `company-mode` makes [existing line numbers disappear](https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode/issues/234). So, either live without line numbers or find out which of both options annoys you less.

Comment: @wasamasa thank you. You can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Line numbers (of the kind that's displayed as a strip with every line number on a window's side) are known for their performance and redrawing issues.  One of them is that they're using the [display margin](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Display-Margins.html#Display-Margins) which interferes with other packages that (indirectly) manipulate the margins.

The more prominent examples would be [auto-complete-mode](https://github.com/auto-complete/auto-complete) and [company-mode](https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode).  `auto-complete-mode` inserts extra text into the buffer for its popup which can be seen by extra whitespace (without line numbers) at the end of the file when completing at a place with sufficient lines of text after it or by lots of non-existant lines (with line numbers) when completing at a place with not enough lines after it. `company-mode` on the other hand does not insert extra text, but does instead mask the margin so that whenever you complete at a place with sufficient lines of text after it, [the line numbers covered by the popup are hidden](https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode/issues/234).  I suggest giving `company-mode` a try since its behaviour is a bit less jarring.

An alternative "solution" would be foregoing `linum-mode` entirely and instead display the current line number in the mode line with `line-number-mode`.